# C++ static local variables not changing value

Tags: c++, static, 3d, local-variables

I'm building a function at the moment in C++ that will let me create a directional ray in my 3D application when I click on the screen. I'm working on some x's and y's calculation at the moment, but the problem is that I do a `std::cout` on x and y, the values stay the same. If I remove the `static` keyword this works fine, but I want to keep it as a static local variable as I will be using this function many times, so what exactly is the problem or what exactly am I doing wrong that's making it print the same value out all the time?

Heres the function:

```
void Mouse::GetClickDirection(D3DXMATRIX projMatrix)
{
    static POINT mousePoint;
    GetCursorPos(&mousePoint);

    ScreenToClient(hwnd, &mousePoint);

    static float width = (float)backBufferWidth;
    static float height = (float)backBufferHeight;

    static float x = (2.0f * mousePoint.x / width - 1.0f) / projMatrix(0, 0);
    static float y = (-2.0f * mousePoint.y / height + 1.0f) / projMatrix(1,1);

    D3DXVECTOR3 origin(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR3 dir(x, y, 1.0f);

    system("CLS");
    std::cout << "X: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Y: " << y << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: "I want to keep it as a static local variable as I will be using this function many times" - I'm not entirely sure you understand what `static` is for.  Your code will do what you expect without the `static` keywords, and you're not actually achieving any kind of useful optimisation by making your variables static

Comment: Why do you think using a static variable is more efficient?

Comment: @Sarien I know it's not like the user will "notice" the difference, but like I said, the function will be used over and over again throughout the lifetime of the program, so (at least to me) it doesn't seem to make sense to keep destroying and creating the same local variable at all :(

Comment: Variable creation/destruction on stack is done by simply by changing the SP or BP registers, which is done already by function call. Compilers can optimize it pretty well.

Comment: Exactly - using `static` like this will just be the cause of many bugs in your code (exactly like the bug you're trying to fix now).  Stop worrying about optimisation, and concentrate on making your code work.  You can come back and optimise later once it does work.

Comment: @Danny Good point but as Erbureth and molbdnilo pointed out it is probably faster than to always go looking for the old value elsewhere in memory.

Comment: @Erbureth Can I just ask if you don't mind - whats SP and BP? (I'll google it later on :P)

Comment: (E/R)SP and (E/R)BP are CPU registers which are pointing to the memory where your application stack is located. They are used to lookup your local variables

Comment: "Premature optimization is root of all evil" - this question proves that very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what `static` keyword means, variable gets initialized only once. From your code, your variables' values are only changed in the initializers, which are executed only once per program execution. As they are dependent on the parameter, they cannot be static. If you want to preserve the values dependent on the parameters, you need to mainain some form of cache, however, it could be even bigger overhead then initializing the variables with every function call.

Comment: you should add to the answer of how to fix it.

Comment: I did, just took some time to write it.

Comment: @pippin1289 - fix is obvious - remove static keyword

Comment: @Slava or you can keep `static`` and move the assignment to a new line. There is more than one solution. I think it would make a better and clearer answer for the OP to describe these.

Comment: @pippin1289 as pointed out in another answer, moving initialization elsewhere is inefficient and doesn't really make any sense

Comment: @pippin1289 I do not see any reason to keep `static` there, except making this function not thread safe. If this variable is changed every time this function is called what is the purpose of making it static?

Comment: @Slava I agree with you, I was just focusing on the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to use static variables here.

Once a local static has been initialized, it isn't updated unless you explicitly assign new values to it.
And what you're doing is initialization, not assignment.

If you're worried about efficiency, it's most likely *less* efficient to use local statics - they need at least an initialization check (on each function call) and possibly a cache miss or two to fetch the values.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make them `static`. `static` local variables are initialized at most once, when the function is first called (formally, when execution first passes through the initializer, but the difference isn't relevant in this code), so on subsequent calls `x` and `y` keep their old values. There's no reason for these to be static.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have to separate variable definition and assignment:

```
static float x;
static float y;
x = (2.0f * mousePoint.x / width - 1.0f) / projMatrix(0, 0);
y = (-2.0f * mousePoint.y / height + 1.0f) / projMatrix(1,1);
```

Because initialization is made only once.

Comment: True, but it doesn't address the fact that the use of `static` at all is entirely unnecessary, and just likely to cause far more bugs in the code in future