# How many times are arguments calculated in multithreaded function-scope static variable initialization?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Suppose we have a following function, which is executed by multiple threads at the same time:

```
void foo()
{
    static SomeClass s{get_first_arg(), get_second_arg()};
}
```

My question is how many times will `get_first_arg` and `get_second_arg` be executed -- exactly once, or *ThreadCount* times, or is it unspecified/implementation-defined behavior?

Comment: static local variables are created only once. [C++ static local variables not changing value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544928/c-static-local-variables-not-changing-value)

Comment: @JasonLiam yeah, I know that. But how many times are its arguments created?

Comment: If the variable `s` is created only once, then why do you think that the arguments will be created/evaluated more than once?

Comment: _"...On all further calls, the declaration is skipped...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables

Comment: @JasonLiam to me it also sounds absurd, but at the same time I couldn't find anywhere which behavior is expected.

Comment: @icant down to the assembly level, arguments are just local variables.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder, do stackoverflow moderators even read questions. None of "duplicated" questions had an answer, and I asked about a completely different thing.

Comment: @RichardCritten yeah, that seems to be an answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There was no need to reopen the question. The [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347433/12002570) already answers the question: *"On all further calls, the declaration is skipped."*

Comment: @SamVarshavchik [This is an exact dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347380/function-executing-once) for this question.

Comment: @icant Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this. Also, this is explained in any [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local static variable `s` initialized only once and the first time control passes through the declaration of that variable. This can be seen from [static local variable's documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347380/function-executing-once):

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier static have static storage duration but are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration (unless their initialization is zero- or constant-initialization, which can be performed before the block is first entered). **On all further calls, the declaration is skipped**.

(emphasis mine)

This in turn means that the arguments `get_first_arg()` and `get_second_arg()` will be evaluated **only once**.

---

Comment: The exact same thing is explained in [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347380/function-executing-once). I closed this as a dupe but then the question was incorrectly reopened.